# center caption of image

Tags: captions

i have code but caption does not in center and not below of image

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}  

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]
\node[anchor=north west,xshift=3cm,yshift=-4cm]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{ABC DEF}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please help that put caption below (0.4cm) and center of image

Thanks
[image]

Comment: You've shifted the image, and a caption is centred on the line.

Comment: @Bernard wow, and how can i shift caption of image?

Comment: If you always use the `\caption*{}` instead of `\caption{}`, you can add TiKz label to your graphic node.

Comment: This  can be done with the `caption` package more or less playing with parameters by trial and error? However, does your real figure have so much white space, or are you trying to have a special layout for a normal image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (n1)[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt,
           xshift=3cm, yshift=-4cm] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\node [below=4mm] at (n1.south) {ABC DEF};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @ferahfeza, oh now I see your comment ... it looks like both of them were loaded almost simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I wrote that comment to OP. I know the important thing here is to help someone.

Comment: Yeah. Please note that the 3cm and -4cm shifts are *not relative to the top-left corner of the page,* because you don't set `inner sep=0` in the node options. Try the provided code with `xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm` and you should see what I mean.

Comment: @frougon, i add `inner sep=0pt.` image is now closer to text border (assuming, that with `shift` is image moved to this border)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the use of the `overlay` and `shift` options, your `tikzpicture` is essentially disconnected from the normal text flow. Your `\caption*` command isn't connected to the `tikzpicture`, it simply places a caption where it is, inside an essentially empty `figure`. Therefore, I suggest to completely omit the `figure` and `center` environments here, since they serve no purpose apart from holding the caption, which is not typeset in the desired place this way.

## First method

If you want a `figure`-like caption below your `tikzpicture`, you can use `\captionof` from the `caption` package inside a node created with `text width=3cm`, for instance:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[inner sep=0, anchor=north west, text width=3cm, shift={(3cm,-4cm)}]
  at (current page.north west)
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}%
   \captionof{figure}{ABC DEF}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used a placement technique (`\node[...] at (...) {...}`) that I find easier to understand than the one used in your example. Also:

- I added `inner sep=0` as part of the node options, **otherwise the offsets you are specifying are not interpreted against the top-left corner of the page** (try with `xshift=0cm` and `yshift=0cm`, or equivalently with `shift={(0cm,0cm)}`).
- I replaced `\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}` with `\usepackage{tikz}`. You might believe that `tikzpagenodes` was needed in your example because it loads `tikz` as a side effect, and you effectively needed `tikz` without loading it explicitly; but **you don't use anything from `tikzpagenodes`**: the `current page` node is part of `tikz`, it doesn't require `tikzpagenodes` in any way, contrary to other nodes you don't use: `current page text area`, `current page marginpar area`, `current page header area` and `current page footer area`. Loading `tikzpagenodes` instead of `tikz` here is just a waste of time and memory.

## Second method

Another way is to prepare the caption text by hand using an option that makes the node a multiline one, such as `align=center` (see *Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text* in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 229 for version 3.1.3 or, for instance, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496154/73317)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[inner sep=0, anchor=north west, align=center, shift={(3cm,-4cm)}]
  at (current page.north west)
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\\
   \textbf{My:} hand-made caption};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Third method

A variant of the second method consists in placing the caption in a separate node: this is what Zarko did in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500158/73317).